# Not able to stream to writer

Tags: java, memory, stream, httpclient

I am trying to stream a file directly to a web service.
For that I created a Writer using

```
     URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9200/tree/public/");
     URLConnection urlconnection=url.openConnection();
     urlconnection.setDoOutput(true);
     ((HttpURLConnection)urlconnection).setRequestMethod("POST");
     ((HttpURLConnection)urlconnection).setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/html");
     Writer out=new OutputStreamWriter(urlconnection.getOutputStream();
```

Next I keep writing data to it as,

```
while(<Read from file , line>){
    out.write(line);
    out.flush();
}

out.close();
```

Here I was hoping that main memory would not be used for storage of the file content as a whole.As in there would be only one line from the file at a time.

But  then on executing the code , the memory usage is skyrocketing and its pretty clear , the content of file is saved somewhere in main memory.
On heap dump found that `PosterOutputStream` is the one holding most of the space.

Comment: How much memory are you talking about? There will be some inevitable buffering under the covers.

Comment: I am talking memory in GB's. i dont care about slight buffering. IF it is "slight"

Comment: Something else is wrong if you're seeing memory in the GB range. We can't tell without more detail.

Comment: I tried to load 23 MB file using the same and it registered 200 MB in the heap. Let me know what more details you want.

Comment: disconnect() is also advised.  You'll have to cast URLConnection to HttpURLConnection.

Comment: After loading every data to the stream , i get the response using "((HttpURLConnection)urlconnection).getResponseCode()" , seems the actualy data transfer happens here only.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling chunked streaming solved the issue.
 ((HttpURLConnection)urlconnection).setChunkedStreamingMode(1024*1024);